# Evaluating $\int\cos(7x)\cos(17x)\cos(27x)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int\cos(7x)\cos(17x)\cos(27x)\mathrm dx$$
I tried using the multiple angle identities but the working out was too tedious and hairy.

Comment: Hint: Use the product-to-sum formulae.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the fact that $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$, this substitution is often helpful, since you can expand the products and end up with a sum of exponential functions, which are easy to integrate. (This is equivalent to using product-to-sum identities, but not so tricky to remember)

Comment: could you elaborate? @MiloBrandt

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$\begin{cases} \cos(a+b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b \\ \cos(a-b) = \cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b \end{cases}$$

Adding the two equations:

$$\cos a \cos b = \frac12 \left( \cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b) \right)$$

You will need to apply this formula three times.

Comment: Applied it & got it!